# What is the HQL equivalent of this Oracle specific query?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a query in one of my projects as below which uses oracle specific stuff. How to rewrite this in HQL?

```
from HotAddressHibId a  where a.expirationTsp >= trunc(SYSDATE)
```

Comment: [`TRUNC(SYSTDATE)`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions220.htm#SQLRF06151) is effectively midnight of the current day.

Comment: @trashgod thats correct but i am wondering if this is orcale specific or a proper HQL

Comment: It is Oracle-specific, but Hib passes anything it doesn't understand to the RDBMS, and so it works. Portability is killed, though.

Comment: Just info for passers-by. I see now, you're moving to HQL, not changing databases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `trunc()` and `sysdate()` are registered as functions in Hibernate dialect for Oracle, so you can simply do this:

```
from HotAddressHibId a  where a.expirationTsp >= trunc(sysdate())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"from HotAddressHibId a where a.expirationTsp >= ?"
```

Then prepare Date object stripping hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds, and bind to the query parameter.

Note that behaviour may change if Oracle is in another timezone.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Hibernate Criteria query with a sqlRestriction:

```
List elements = session.createCriteria(HotAddressHibId.class)
    .add( Restrictions.sqlRestriction("expiration_tsp >= trunc(SYSDATE)" )
    .list();
```